# Bootstrap Carousel Slider - slide out direction ( next and prev )

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel, direction, bootstrap-carousel

I have the Bootstrap Carousel Slider and when he slides (automaticly) to the next slide, the old picture move to the left side, but i need the effect to the right side. Can someone help me out with this one?

regards,
Artur

Comment: Maybe you can check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098929/how-to-make-my-slide-toggle-from-left-to-right-in-bootstrap

Comment: This question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962585/bootstrap-carousel-slide-left-to-right Hope this helps